# Definition: Convergence in probability on a set

Tags: probability-theory, definition

I know what it mean that a sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ converges to a random variable $X$ in probability. But what does it exactly mean that  $(X_n)$ converges to $X$ in probability *on a (measurable) set $A$?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_n \to X$ in probability on $A$ if $P(A \cap (|X_n-X| >\epsilon)) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So am I right that for $P(A) \neq 0$ convergence in probability on the set A would be the same as saying convergence in probability given (conditional on) A?

Comment: Yes, you are right.